# Syntax for multidimensional arrays - x[?,?] and x[?][?]

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I'm using https://js.do/ as a sandbox for simple scripts and `document.write` to print results. I'm working with multidimensional arrays, with code such as

```
var x = [];

x[1, 2] = 0;
```

However, I'm a little confused on what exactly `document.write` is printing.

On researching multidimensional arrays in JS, I found no mention of the notation used above, but rather `x[1][2]` was used in the examples found instead (ie. an array inside of an array).

I can't remember where I first came across the above way of using multidimensional arrays - perhaps someone could provide a link to enlighten me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x[1, 2] = 0;` assigns `0` to index `2` of `x`, where [comma](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) operator `,` evaluates last value of `0, 2` expressions as an index of `x` at bracket notation

```js
var x = [];

x[1, 2] = 0;

console.log(x[2] === 0);
```

Comment: Oh wow - I'd mistakenly thought that was the correct notation, but it was completely wrong. Thankfully only started the multidimensional array part a while ago. It explains what I was getting from `document.write` as well

Answer (score 0):

The syntax with the comma is incorrect, but apparently doesn't cause a syntax error. It is being interpreted by simply taking the last value, so the example `x[1,2] = 0` is being views as `x[2] = 0`. That creates an array with `0` in the third position (index 2), `[undefined,undefined,0]`. As that gets written to the DOM, the undefined is ignored, but a comma is still added. So your output is `,,0`.